# How to filter unique value from a list in R

Tags: r, list, filter

I want to extract discharge (Disch) values for a specific rank in a list. The list consists of Date, Months, Disch, and Rank for each month. There are uneven number of rows in every month. If I were to filter the discharge values for every month in the list for Rank = 1, then what do I need to do? Also in the original data set I have duplicate rank and its corresponding discharge value, how can I filter a single value of discharge for each month for the given rank?

```
S <- split(Sampledata3, Sampledata3$Months) #Split the original data into different months. 
This is how my list looks like: 
> S
$`1`
         Date Months Disch Rank
4  1943-01-01      1   255    1
5  1945-01-14      1   450    2
10 1962-01-18      1  1204    4
12 1972-01-15      1   635    3
16 1989-01-20      1  1204    4

$`3`
         Date Months Disch Rank
6  1945-03-14      3   215    1
17 1992-03-29      3   450    2

$`4`
         Date Months Disch Rank
8  1960-04-23      4   120    1
14 1981-04-11      4   154    2

$`5`
        Date Months Disch Rank
7 1954-05-04      5   360    2
9 1960-05-09      5   145    1

$`6`
         Date Months Disch Rank
3  1967-06-16      6   400    2
15 1986-06-20      6   154    1

$`8`
         Date Months Disch Rank
13 1977-08-15      8  1456    1

$`10`
        Date Months Disch Rank
1 1938-10-01     10  1000    1
2 1954-10-27     10  1200    2

$`12`
         Date Months Disch Rank
11 1968-12-19     12   752    1

Sample data:
> Date<- as.Date(c('1938-10-01','1954-10-27', '1967-06-16','1943-01-01','1945-01-14','1945-03-14','1954-05-04','1960-04-23','1960-05-09','1962-01-18','1968-12-19','1972-01-15','1977-08-15','1981-04-11','1986-06-20','1989-01-20','1992-03-29'))
> Months<- c('Oct','Oct','Jun','Jan','Jan','Mar','May','Apr','May','Jan','Dec','Jan','Aug','Apr','Jun','Jan','Mar')
> Dis<-c('1000','1200','400','255','450','215','360','120','145','1204','752','635','1456','154','154','1204','450')
> Sampledata<-data.frame("Date"=Date,"Months"=Months,"Disch"=Dis)
```

Comment: Is your data in a list or did you just do that as a step towards your desired output?

Comment: Original data is not in a list format. Splitting the big data set into a list form was recommended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option with `list` would be (in case the OP already have an existing `list`)

```
library(tidyverse)
map(S, ~ .x %>%
           filter(Rank == 1))
```

If there are duplicate 'Rank' then remove the duplicate with

```
map(S, ~ .x %>%
              filter(Rank == 1, !duplicated(Rank))
```

Or using `slice` with `which`

```
map(S, ~ .x %>%
             slice(which(Rank == 1)[1])
```

Comment: Thank you, this approach is working! How can I modify this approach if I have different rank numbers for different months?

Comment: @Roger  It would be easier with `map2` i.e. `map2(S, vectorOfMonths, ~ .x %>% filter(Rank == .y, !duplicated(Rank))`

Comment: map2 is working very well for me! I need to use the filtered discharge values for further calculation. Is there any way map 2 can only display the discharge values for each month rather than the complete row?

Comment: @Roger Sure, Try `map2(S, vectorOfMonths, ~ .x %>% filter(Rank == .y, !duplicated(Rank)) %>% select(Disch))`

Comment: adding select gave an error
Error in UseMethod("select_") : 
  no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "logical"

Comment: @Roger  What is the `dplyr` version you have?  I used `packageVersion("dplyr")
[1] ‘0.8.1’`  If you have `select` from other packages, use `%>% dplyr::select(Disch)`

Comment: Oh fixed the error by adding bracket before the last pipe operator map2(S, vectorOfMonths, ~ .x %>% filter(Rank == .y, !duplicated(Rank))  %>% select(Disch)) That worked! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

or use base R `tapply` or `aggregate`, both of which can apply a function to groups of your data and return an answer for each group but in different default forms

```
#also recommend that you set stringsAsFactors=FALSE when you initialize data.frame as sample dataset
Sampledata <- data.frame(Date=Date,Months=Months,Disch=Dis, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
Sampledata$Disch <- as.numeric(Sampledata$Disch) #convert to numeric class
tapply(X=Sampledata$Disch, INDEX=Sampledata$Months, FUN=max)
#Apr  Aug  Dec  Jan  Jun  Mar  May  Oct 
#154 1456  752 1204  400  450  360 1200

aggregate(Disch ~ Months, data = Sampledata, FUN=max)
#   Months Disch
#1    Apr   154
#2    Aug  1456
#3    Dec   752
#4    Jan  1204
#5    Jun   400
#6    Mar   450
#7    May   360
#8    Oct  1200
```